# Show that $\dfrac{\phi (n)}{n}=\sum\limits_{d|n} \dfrac{\mu (d)}{d}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, solution-verification, analytic-number-theory

This problem is from Ram Murtys book *Problems in analytic number theory*. In his solutions it only says that this is an immediate result when combining the Möbius inversion formula: $$f(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}g(d) \ \ \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N} \Leftrightarrow g(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu (d)f(n/d) \ \ \ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$$ and gauss theorem: $$\sum\limits_{d|n}\phi (d)=n.$$ I cant get it right though...

Here is one thing that I have tried thus far:

Let $f(n)=\phi (n)$ in Möbius inversion formula. We wish to show that $g(d)\stackrel{?}{=}\dfrac{\mu (d)}{d}$. We have that $$g(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu (d)f(n/d)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu (d)\phi (n/d).$$ From here I have tried a bunch of things which seemed unjustified and did not actually get me anywhere.

Can someone give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

Comment: You should try $g(n) = \phi(n)$.

Comment: Thanks! I see how I can solve it now. I think.

$g(n)=\phi (n)\Rightarrow f(n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}g(d)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\phi (d)=n$. Which implies that $g(n)=\phi (n)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu (d)f(n/d)=\sum\limits_{d|n}\mu (d)\cdot \dfrac{n}{d}$. Thus $\dfrac{\phi (n)}{n}=\sum\limits_{d|n} \dfrac{\mu (d)}{d}$.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800118/proof-of-phin-sum-nd-mud-cdot-frac-nd?rq=1).

Comment: First show that both sides are multiplicative so that it suffices prove the identity only for prime powers.

Answer (score 2):

$$ {\rm Id}(n)=n=\sum_{d|n}\varphi(d)=(\varphi*1)(n) $$
Therefore using Möbius inversion formula, we have
$$ \varphi(n)=({\rm Id}*\mu)(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)\frac{n}{d}=n\sum_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d} $$